# Entity Framework Core - InitialCreate passes with no errors but nothing is created in SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to create a database using .NET 5.0 and what happens is correct built after `Add-Migration InitialCreate` but nothing created in the SQL Server.

I spent 2 days in looking what's going wrong but I couldn't find anything. What provoked me to post here my question is the surprise when the migration passed with no error even when I typed wrong connection string with no existent server name (both when the string is in `UseSQLServer` in `ConfigureServices` as well in `appsettings.json`)..

Any idea what happens and how to solve it?

The version of Entity Framework Core I've installed is 5.0.13

Answer (score 0):

There is a second step that is missing here :

```
Update-Database
```

in PowerShell or :

```
dotnet ef database update
```

in NET core CLI

Read more here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Thank you, there are errors now :)

Comment: Perhaps the readers should know _what errors_, to be able to guess the reason :)